# How to properly replace day in a dynamically allocated C array

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

I am working on a basic framework to dynamically allocate array with the C language.  I have created a function to create an array of strings titled `init_string_vector`.  Data can be appended to the array with the `append_string_vector` function and data can be de-allocated from the heap with the `free_string_array` function.  I am currently working on a function titled `replace_string_vector_index` that allows a user to pass an array index to the function as well as a pointer to the string array.  If the array is typed as a `STRING` array and the index is not out of bounds, the function should replace the existing data with the string that a user passes to the function.

The `replace_string_vector_index` function appears to work properly and does replace the string at the index with the other string the user passed to the function.  However, the `free_string_array` function no longer works once I have used to `replace_string_vector_index` function to act on the array.  This makes me think that the process within the function is causing an issue, but I cannot see how.  An example is shown below.  When the `free_string_array` function fails, I get the following error, `free(): invalid pointer`.

vector.h

```
#ifndef ARRAY_H
#define ARRAY_H

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

typedef enum
{
    FLOAT,
    DOUBLE,
    CHAR,
    INT,
    STRING
} dat_type;
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

typedef struct
{
    char **array;
    size_t len;
    int elem;
    dat_type dat;
} StringVector;
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

int string_vector_mem_alloc(StringVector *array, size_t num_indices);
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

StringVector init_string_vector();
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

int append_string_vector(StringVector *s, char *value);
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

void free_string_array(StringVector *array);
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

int replace_string_vector_index(StringVector *array, int index, char string[]);
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

vector.c

```
#include "vector.h"

int string_vector_mem_alloc(StringVector *array, size_t num_indices) {
    // Determine the total memory allocation and assign to pointer
    void *pointer;
    pointer = malloc(num_indices * array->elem);

    // If memory is full fail gracefully
    if (pointer == NULL) {
        printf("Unable to allocate memory, exiting.\n");
        free(pointer);
        return 0;
    }
    // Allocate resources and instantiate Array
    else {
        array->array = pointer;
        array->len = 0;
        return 1;
    }
}
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

StringVector init_string_vector() {
    StringVector array;
    array.dat = STRING;
    array.elem = sizeof(char *);
    string_vector_mem_alloc(&array, array.elem);
    return array;
}
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

int append_string_vector(StringVector *array, char *value) {
    value = strdup(value);
    if (!value) {
        return -1;
    }
    array->len++;
    char **resized = realloc(array->array, sizeof(char *)*array->len + 1);
    if (!resized) {
        free(value);
        return -1;
    }
    resized[array->len-1] = value;
    array->array = resized;
    return 0;
}
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

void free_string_array(StringVector *array) {
    if (array != NULL) {
        for (int i = 0; i < array->len; i++) {
            free(array->array[i]);
        }
    }
    free(array->array);
    // Reset all variables in the struct
    array->array = NULL;
    array->len = 0;
    array->elem = 0;
}
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

int replace_string_vector_index(StringVector *array, int index, char string[]) {
    if (array->dat != STRING) {
        printf("Array data type must be a STRING");
        return 0;
    }
    if (index > array->len) {
        printf("Index is greater than array length");
        return 0;
    }
    * (char **) ((char *) array->array + index * array->elem) = string;
    return 1;
}
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "vector.h"
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    StringVector arr_test = init_string_vector();
    char one[] = "Hello";
    char two[] = "World";
    char three[] = "Hello";
    char four[] = "Goodbye";
    append_string_vector(&arr_test, one);
    append_string_vector(&arr_test, two);
    append_string_vector(&arr_test, three);
    append_string_vector(&arr_test, four);
    // I can free the array at this point 
    free_string_array(&arr_test)

    StringVector arr_test = init_string_vector();
    append_string_vector(&arr_test, one);
    append_string_vector(&arr_test, two);
    append_string_vector(&arr_test, three);
    append_string_vector(&arr_test, four);
    replace_string_vector_index(&arr_test, 1, one);
    // - Once I envoke replace_string_vector_index, free_string_array
    //   no longer works, and I get an invalid pointer error.
    free_string_array(&arr_test);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the requirements for your `replace_string_vector_index` function, you should first free the memory of `array->array[index]`, then assign the result of `strdup(string)` to that element.

No casting needed, no complex pointer arithmetic. Just simply:

```
free(array->array[index]);
array->array[index] = strdup(string);
```

---

What happens now (I think) is that you make `array->array[index]` point to the *array* that contains the string (i.e. you forget the `strdup` step). An array that wasn't allocated by `malloc`, and which can't be passed to `free`.

Since you will pass it to `free` as part of `free_string_array` you will have *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Wow, I got so focused on pointer arithmetic that I missed the simple solution.  Thank you!